# GridDB error code 1002: How to troubleshoot 'Container not found' error?

Tags: database, griddb

I am using GridDB for a project, and while working with the database, I encountered error code 1002, which states "Container not found."

**Here's what I have tried so far and what I was expecting:**
I have verified that the container I am trying to access exists in GridDB by checking the database schema. Additionally, I have double-checked the spelling and case sensitivity of the container name in my code to ensure it matches the actual container name.

Despite these checks, I am still receiving the "Container not found" error. I was expecting to be able to access and manipulate the container's data without any issues.

Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting this error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.